# Remove item from array and html list using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a javascript array called `names[]` which stores names. (ofcourse)
The names are also stored in list items in my `html` document, I have this code that removes a name when you click on it;

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on('click', 'li', function(){
        $(this).remove();
    });
});
```

Can anyone tell me how I remove the same item from the array `names[]`?

**UPDATE:** `names[]` is defined as follows:

```
function submit() {
    var theName = document.getElementById("enter").value;

    if (theName == "" || theName.length == 0) {
        return false;
    }

    names.push(theName);
    document.getElementById("name").children[0].innerHTML += "<li>" + names[names.length - 1] + "</li>";
    document.getElementById("enter").value = "";
}
```

This is done with an `<input>`.

Comment: Please show us how `names` is defined.

Comment: function submit()
{
    var theName = document.getElementById("enter").value;
    if (theName == "" || theName.length == 0)
    {
       return false;
    }
    names.push(theName);
    document.getElementById("name").children[0].innerHTML += "<li>" + names[names.length - 1] + "</li>";
    document.getElementById("enter").value = "";
}
This is done with <input>

Comment: FYI, Next time you want to add details to your question, please add the edits to the actual post rather than putting them here in the comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Array.prototype.remove = function(item) {
    var index = this.indexOf(item);
    if (index > -1) {
        this.splice(index, 1);
        return true;
    }

    return false;
};    

$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on('click', 'li', function(){
        var text = $(this).text();
        names.remove(text);
        $(this).remove();
    });
});
```

Comment: -edit
I accidently pressed a button, it does work, thanks, but a explanation would be nice.